# .NET 4.6.1 - '?'-operator for null checks and CA1062

Tags: c#, fxcop

Since .NET 4.6.1 the '?'-operator can be used to shorten null checks. However FxCop doesn't seem to recognize the check, regarding rule CA1062:Validate arguments of public methods. Is there a newer version of this rule available that digs the null check?

Comment: Looks like a bug. There is a similar bug with CA2213:  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1372682/unnecessary-warning-ca2213

Comment: Are you referring to inline if's? Those are quite a lot older than .Net 4.6.1. The shortened null check is the _double_ question mark: ``var result = testvar ?? defaultifnull;``

Comment: @Nye no, `var propValueOrNull = nullableParam?.Property`.

Comment: Oh, nifty. Haven't worked on the latest frameworks.

Comment: `public static string SomeMethod4(SomeClass sc)
{
  // try to avoid CA1062 violation by using the '?'-operator but CA1062  violation is fired anyway!

if (sc?.Name != null)
 {
       return sc.Name;
  }

  return "n/a";
}
`

Comment: The following usage of the '?'-Operator doesn't produce a CA1062 Violation:
  
`public static string SomeMethod3(string h)  
{  
 // avoid CA1062 violation by using the '?'-Operator  
 string sub = h?.Substring(0, 5);  
 return sub;  
 }`